# Java runtime binary shows different results

Tags: java, runtime, binaries

I'm trying to run a binary using my Java code but it's giving me a different result than when I would run it myself from my terminal.

Java code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/go/Sentiment";
String command = path + " " + "\"i love this\"";
System.out.println(command);

Process p = rt.exec(command);
Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
String output = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

> /home/ninesalt/repositories/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp/src/main/go/Sentiment
> "i love this"
>
> 0

However when I run in that same exactly command in my terminal I get 1 instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: Binary returns different code. Only way to figure it out is to debug.

Comment: @karoldowbecki So Apparently the command only passes the first word in my argument for some reason. [command] "i". I think i might need to format the string in a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) to avoid problems in quoting the arguments:

```
String command = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/go/Sentiment";
String arg = "i love this";

Process p = rt.exec(new String[] { command, arg });
```